# Trying to place image on canvas of side of each shape with three.js

Tags: three.js, html5-canvas

I am trying to place image on top of the background color shown on each side of the cube. It doesn't display nor does it show an error on the JavaScript console.
The code here is showing what is replacing the generateTexture2() function shown in the jsFiddle JavaScript pane.

```
function generateTexture2() {

        // draw a circle in the center of the canvas
        var size = 256;

        // create canvas
        var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        canvas.width = size;
        canvas.height = size;

        // get context
        var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
        imageObj.onload = function() {
          context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        };


        return canvas;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XGWGn/118/

Answer (score 1):

The `mix()` function in GLSL is defined as the linear interpolation between two values, based on some factor. i.e.

`value = mix( c1, c2, f )` is equal to `value = c1 * (1 - f) + c2 * f;`

it is actually confusing that `factor` is sometimes associated with the `alpha` value in the documentation.

So in your fragment shader if you change the `factor` value you will see the effect you are looking for.

```
factor = 0.9999; // should see the second texture
gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( tColor.rgb, tColor2.rgb, factor ), 1.0 ) * dotProduct;
```

or `factor = 0.0001` // should see the first texture

if you use `factor = 0.5;` you will see the blending of the two textures.

(don't know why using `factor = 0` or `factor = 1` does not work)

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nv3680x7/1/

Comment: I put in the factor as .1 and the base background shows well, but if put the factor as .9, it makes the whole shape look very transparent. The image or 2nd texture doesn't show in any scenario.

Comment: in my fiddle or your fiddle?

Comment: In what would be my fiddle, not all of my code is consolidated in it; let me update it, one moment.

Comment: The visual idea is to scale the image (when and if I can get it show), so it looks smaller than the side that it is on, so that the blue background shows around it. I didn't account for that in the code currently.
http://jsfiddle.net/XGWGn/121/

Comment: I am not concerned about scaling; just having the image to show.

Comment: your darth-vader texture is not showing up. what is wrong with my fiddle? if you put `factor = 0.5` you do see the blending of the two textures.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your fiddle, your code works. I'm just wondering why my darth-vader texture isn't showing up. I thought there was something in factor that may have influenced it or something in the mix function.